# FullCalendar moment.js deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm having an issue with fullCalendar. The dependency library moment.js will output in consolle the following error.

`Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true, _l: undefined, _i: 1, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]`

I've looked here on SO and it's seems an error related to the event passed date format. I've checked the database table who extract the data and the stored format is a DATE like this `Y-m-d` so every event date is something like `2018-09-19`. Is there a way to fix this? It's strange because I'm using the same plugin in others project and it doesn't give me this error and the stored data are in the same format with the db column set as `DATE`.

PHP code for events

```
$events = array();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM matches');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $result){

  $events[] = array(
    'id' => $result['id'],
    'title' =>  $result['competition'],
    'start' => DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' ,$result['matchDay']),
    'end' => DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' ,$result['matchDay'])
  );

}

echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

Comment: The is not in iso format. You have to give the iso format date there. Format the date like this `moment(Your_date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS')`.  BTW it is always better if you share your code.

Comment: But this is the first time I've this problem, as i wrote I've a database with the dates and on another application it's not generating the warning

Comment: And you are using moment there?

Comment: @MustafaMamun yes, it's a dependency of fullCalendar

Comment: I am not sure which version of moment you are using there. But with the new version of moment if you provide some date that does't follow iso format or RFC2822 then you will get this warning.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try to reformat the extracted date using php then I will pass them to the fullCalendar plugin.

Comment: Or you can use something like this `moment(your_time).toDate()`

Comment: But in this way i need to fetch first the data and then pass them to fullCalendar, now I've the json outputted from a php script, so maybe it's better to use the `DateTime` class

Comment: I cannot say really what would be better for you without having a look on your code. But you have to format the array of events/event you are passing to Fullcalendar as it want it to be. Which is the date has to in right format.

Comment: @MustafaMamun php code added

Comment: Check answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
 'title' => DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' ,$result['competition']),
 'end' => DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' ,$result['matchDay'])
```

You are telling it to create a date with this 'Y-m-d' format, Try to give

```
'Y-m-d H:i:s' format and see what happens
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also made a mistake with the title key of the json. I will try your fix.

Comment: I've checked the json response, it will output a false for the start and the end keys. I want to test without the `DateTime::createFromFormat` to see if data are outputted correctly. Otherwise I need to rewrite the code

Comment: glad to help :)